# Whats wrong in this Query Mysql?

Tags: mysql

[image]Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this mysql query?
There is one record matching, so I guess that `count` should be 1 instead of 0.

```
SELECT c.bookmark_count
     , f.category_id cat_id
     , f.unfollow_at
     , CASE bookmark_count WHEN c.id = f.follower_category_id 
                           THEN 1 
                           ELSE 0 END count
     , c.id
     , f.follower_category_id follow_id
     , c.user_id 
  FROM categories c
  LEFT 
  JOIN following_follower_categories f 
    ON f.follower_category_id = c.id 
 WHERE c.user_id = 26;



bookmark_count  cat_id  unfollow_at          count    id    follow_id user_id
             4      72  0000-00-0000:00:00       0    172         l72   26
            10   NULL   NULL                     0    164        NULL   26
             1   NULL   NULL                     0    173        NULL   26
             9   NULL   NULL                     0    199        NULL   26
             3   NULL   NULL                     0    200        NULL   26
             3   NULL   NULL                     0    201        NULL   26
             1   NULL   NULL                     0    202        NULL   26
             0   NULL   NULL                     0    203        NULL   26
             3   NULL   NULL                     0    204        NULL   26
             0   NULL   NULL                     0    206        NULL   26
             0   NULL   NULL                     0    207        NULL   26
             0   NULL   NULL                     0    208        NULL   26
             0   NULL   NULL                     0    209        NULL   26
             1   NULL   NULL                     0    210        NULL   26
```

Comment: maybe remove 'bookmark_count' from the case statement

Comment: @Strawberry: Dont edit any Code. why you added alais c, f etc. on my code. Dont do it for others. if you dnt know answer jst skip it. not edit. ok

Comment: Just to make it readable.

Comment: @Strawberry - please don't edit code in questions. You might end up masking the actual problem

Comment: previoulsy was also readable. Why u add alias.  i have to rewrite my logic again. dnt edit any question if you dnt know answer. You also delete the image.

Comment: @Kamalpreet - you can just rollback the edits to your original version and then incorporate any useful edits.

Comment: @ChrisF : Yes, he did.

Comment: @ChrisF: Gordon Already answered to my question edited by Strawberry. I just use that logic. Nowq, if i edit Gordon answer will be wrong. it is better if Strawberyy not edit any question for 2 points

Comment: @Kamalpreet - Strawberry has more than 2k rep so doesn't earn anything from edits.

Comment: it's ok Chris. but editing the question doesnot make sense. i am not saying for repo. it waste my time. i respect him, because he is Quite experience person. i am new in technology

Comment: @ChrisF, Kamalpreet -  I think the only changes I made were cosmetic but please advise if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Strawberry : No, You are not mistaken, as i am learning new things. You code give me good idea, how to write code.. but sometime you know. i guess you can understand. Sorry if you mind in my previous messgae

Comment: @Strawberry: Can you please answer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683086/how-to-handle-this-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment40139973_25683086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression is not syntactically correct in all databases but it does work in MySQL:

```
 (CASE bookmark_count WHEN c.id = f.follower_category_id 
                      THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0
  END) count
```

This is essentially equivalent to the following logic:

```
if c.id = f.follower_category_id and bookmark_count = 1 then 1
else if c.id <> f.follower_category_id and bookmark_count = 0 then 1
else 0
```

(This is ignoring `NULL` values for simplicity.)

That is, the expression `c.id = f.follower_category_id` is not treated as a condition, it is treated as an integer expression that is `1` for true and `0` for else.

I am not sure what you really want.  Perhaps it is:

```
 (CASE WHEN c.id = f.follower_category_id 
       THEN bookmark_count
       ELSE 0
  END) count
```

Alternatively, if you just want a flag as to whether or not there is a match, then you can use:

```
(f.follower_category_id is not null) as count
```

Comment: @Gordan Linoff: Can you please answer this too..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683086/how-to-handle-this-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment40139973_25683086