# How to handle this mysql query with case and limit Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have follow this user category button. When i click on that button, it will save that record into  following_follower_categories. i want their records for that category into my category

tables having their name 
**Categories, following_follower_categories, bookmarks, user_bookmarks**
having their fields like

1) Bookmarks contains 
**id,  and other details**

2) user_bookmarks  table

**user_id, bookmark_id, category_id**

3) following_follower_categories

****user_id( other user_id to whom i am following)**

**follower_user_id( current user id)**

**follower_category_id(where my bookmarks will go )**

**category_id(other user category_id)**

4)  category

**id ,cat_name , user_id**

Now i want to achieve  is  when i am following someone cateogory 
I want their artilce into my that category **with limit and in conditions**.

Here is mysql query which i tried to do .

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM (SELECT f.category_id cat_id,
               `user_bookmarks`.`id` AS `user_bookmark_id`,
               `bookmark_id`,
               `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`,
               `user_bookmarks`.`category_id`,
               `bookmark_website`,
               `bookmark_title`,
               `bookmark_preview_image`,
               `pdf_txt_flag`,
               `youtube_video`,
               `snapshot_preview_image`,
               (CASE
                    WHEN `user_bookmarks`.`category_id` =
                                               f.follower_category_id
                        THEN (SELECT *
                                FROM `user_bookmarks` ub
                              WHERE ub.category_id= f.follower_category_id)
                        ELSE 0
               END) `mode`,
               @r:= CASE
                        WHEN `user_bookmarks`.`category_id` = @g THEN @r+1
                        ELSE @r:=1
                    END `rank`,
               @g:=category_id
          FROM `user_bookmarks`
               LEFT JOIN `following_follower_categories` f
                   ON f.follower_category_id =`user_bookmarks`.`category_id`
               LEFT JOIN `bookmarks`
                   ON `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` = `bookmarks`.`id`
               LEFT JOIN `categories`
                   ON `user_bookmarks`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
               JOIN (SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t1
         WHERE `user_bookmarks`.`category_id` IN (161,
                                                  83,
                                                  107,
                                                  73)
      ORDER BY `user_bookmarks`.`created_at` DESC) t
WHERE t.rank <=10
```

I know above query is wrong. Can anybody gives me idea how to do this. Can we handle this in mysql itself.

here is my expected output. i need it **within in and limit clause**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for the tables, and the expected result set?

Comment: @NevilleK: it will take too much time to create result set. i will update it , when i created

Comment: @Kamalpreet, I've started trying to answer your question ([schema fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df66a)), but I could not understand what do you want. Please, edit the question and explain better what is your expected output.

Comment: @Zanon: i made some edit. pls

Answer (score 0):

One issue looks like the expression for the `mode` column. The subquery in the CASE expression should return one expression, and one row.  Rather than `SELECT *` it should be `SELECT <expr>`, and there should be a LIMIT 1 clause if there's a possibility that it returns more than one row.

If you need more than one expression, then you'd either need to repeat that CASE expression, with a different subquery, or you might want a JOIN operation.